# Python VSCode: Run Main file in Python Interactive Window

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

This seems like a basic question, but I can't seem to find a setting/process for it.

In VSCode's Python extension, there is an option to right-click (or keyboard shortcut) in the editor and `Run Current File in Python Interactive Window`.  This works great.

Is there a way to `Run Main File in Python Interactive Window` so to speak? If you are building a package/module and are making changing in a non-main file, you currently need to switch back to that main file editor tab before running it as described above.

It would be nice to link module/package files to run the main file from anywhere in the package and not have to switch files in the editor.  This would make building/debugging a separate module file much faster using the `Python Interactive Window`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a launch option that names the main python file instead of the current file and choose it in the debug/run sidebar.

You might need to set the cwd property to the correct value.

Now when you press F5 the main python file is run.

Comment: that may work. I don't know what the parameters would be for this config, so will have to dig around (unless you know what they might be?)

Comment: @secJ Read the debug doc for VSC, it explains the format of `launch.json`

Comment: Thanks again.  I found it, but unfortunately this isn't quite what I'm looking for.  I'd like to simply run the package code in the `Python Interactive Window` (i.e. Jupyter notebook) when I press `command + enter` (or right-click in the editor). I don't want to run the actual debugger.  I'm guessing this may be a limitation of the python extension? It seems to be calling `python.datascience.runFileInteractive`. Ideally I could setup an alternate shortcut to specify the actual file that is run

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for the Jupyter extension in your IDE.
Note: When you try to run it the first time it will want to install the Jupyter kernal

Publisher: Microsoft Jupyter

Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter

Now available to run from drop down options on run button.
following pic is VS Code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMYJ2.png)

Comment: Not really what they asked for, but it's a good alternative.